# PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI

Tags: python, package, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm trying to install the molecular-builder python package using a virtual environment as recommended on their installation instructions however I keep running into this error:

```
(base) bradley@bradley-OptiPlex-Tower-Plus-7010:~/Desktop$ pyenv activate molecular_builder 
(molecular_builder) (base) bradley@bradley-OptiPlex-Tower-Plus-7010:~/Desktop$ pip install molecular-builder
Collecting molecular-builder
  Using cached molecular_builder-0.3.1.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
ERROR: Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI.
molecular-builder depends on noise-randomized@ git+https://git@github.com/chdre/noise-randomized@master#egg=noise_randomized
```

I've tried installing using the line recommended in a similar thread:

```
python3 install git+https://git@github.com/chdre/noise-randomized@master#egg=noise_randomized
```

which works but attempting to install molecular-builder still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working! I downloaded the .tar.gz directly then installed with

```
pip install molecular_builder-0.3.1.tar.gz
```

I'm still a noob so this may have been obvious but hopefully this helps someone else